# Pyspark: write json from schema

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, nested

I need to delete certain entries from nested Json files. As far as I know, I cant just delete them from the json file directly, so my next choice would be to load them into a pyspark dataframe, delete the entries there, create a new json with the same schema (& preferably the same name) and replace the old json file. I have extracted the schema into a json file, is there a way to write the dataframe back into a json file, somehow parsing the extracted schema?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Spark DataFrameWriter` also has a method `mode()` to specify `SaveMode;` the argument to this method either takes below string or a constant from `SaveMode` class.

`overwrite` – mode is used to overwrite the existing file, alternatively, you can use `SaveMode.Overwrite`.

`append` – To add the data to the existing file, alternatively, you can use `SaveMode.Append`.

`ignore` – Ignores write operation when the file already exists, alternatively you can use `SaveMode.Ignore`.

`errorifexists` or error – This is a default option when the file already exists, it returns an error, alternatively, you can use `SaveMode.ErrorIfExists`.

```
df2.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json("/tmp/spark_output/zipcodes.json")
```